# jqeasy characters count display next to textbox (postfix)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to turn this script display the character count next to textbox  instead of display below of textbox?

Here is there source link http://web.archive.org/web/20150317063551/http://www.jqeasy.com/jquery-character-counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqEasy creates a div showing the character count. This div has the class `jqEasyCounterMsg` which you are free to add on your code.

I was able to do this by adding styles to the `jqEasyCounterMsg` css class.

Depending on the style you are looking for, you can do something like this:

```
.jqEasyCounterMsg {
    display: inline-block;
/* other styles here */
}
```

Hope this helps!